# Published sharepoint app is different from the debug version in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sharepoint, visual-studio-2015, office365, sharepoint-apps

I'm working on a sharepoint add-in. I have a list based on some content types. When I debug the application using visual studio, the hidden site columns are hidden which is correct. But when I package the app, upload then add it to site content in office365, the hidden columns are no more hidden and the lookup columns are not working... Any clue?

Comment: It was a problem of features activation order. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40136/how-can-i-make-sure-the-features-in-my-solution-activate-in-the-correct-order

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your are taking/installing the right build (Release vs Debug) and make sure to remove the existing app with all previously created artifacts before deploying the new build.